# discord.js - Has role give permission

Tags: role, discord.js

So basically I am trying to make a ticket sort of discord bot using discord.js.

The concept: someone says +help then it DMs a member, who has said +onduty and has a role of something like "Helper".

I need to work out how to detect the role and add them to a set who are "on duty".

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do stuff like this in my bot (snipet from my [example bot's](https://github.com/DonovanDMC/DiscordJSExampleBot/blob/master/bot.js) kick command):

```
// This command should be limited to staff. In this example we just hardcode the role names.
// Please read up on Array.some() to understand this bit: 
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["STAFF","Helper"].includes(r.name))) {
    return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
}
```

A little bit of the documentation on this:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles

`message.member.roles` contains a collection of the members roles

we can use `.some()` to go through them and see if the user has a role
`.some()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

So to go through all guild members to see if they have `helper` then, if they also have `on duty`:

```
// assuming the Message is in a variable called message

var gm=Array.from(message.guild.members);
for(var member in gm) {
    if(gm[member].roles.some(r=>["Helper"].includes(r.name))) {
        if(gm[member].roles.some(r=>["on duty"].includes(r.name))) {
            gm[member].send(`Help command ran:\nUser: ${message.author.tag}\nContent: ${message.content.replace("+help ","")}`);
        }
    }
}
```

if a user runs the command `+help <what they need help with>` it will send to someone in the guild with the roles `helper` and `on duty`:

(using my Discord tag for an example)


What was ran: `+help I need some help with something`

"Help command ran:
User: Donovan_DMC#1337
Content: I need some help with something"
(without quotes)

as for this

> I need to work out how to detect the role and add them to a set who are "on duty".

I assume you mean that when someone with the role `helper` runs the command `+onduty` they get the role `on duty`.

```
var roleid=message.guild.roles.find("name","on duty").id;
if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["Helper"].includes(r.name))) {
    message.member.addRole(roleid);
}
```

A few documentation links to hopefully help you understand this
`message`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message
`message.guild`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild
`message.guild.roles`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles

and for removing the role it's almost exactly the same

```
var roleid=message.guild.roles.find("name","on duty").id;
if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["Helper"].includes(r.name))) {
    message.member.removeRole(roleid);
}
```

In summary a basic bot for this you could have something like [this](https://pastebin.com/Xfdk8Hh5).
^ I've added some extra checks for already having the role, not having it, and made it where the prefix can be changed

I've tested it, and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: forgot to declare the client in the pastebin post, updated the pastebin post.

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped.

Comment: I saw one issue you put autor or something like that instead of author. will test this later I'm on iPad. Thank you very much for your help; if I ever publish this I will credit you.  (NOTE: Don't worry I won't Copy the script exactly I will edit parts of it lol)

Comment: I see it (I didn't read properly). It says I am missing a bracket somewhere after the argument list. I'll add you on discord as this might be easier to talk. My name is ProfBlox#9546. I'll friend you.

Comment: I've tracked the bug, I built it by hand and forgot to close some things and as you said, `autor` instead of `author`, I've fully tested it now and it worked just as said. (updated pastebin link; new paste)

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I accepted your friend on discord.